# Netty 3.10 Final Doesnt Have Channel.WriteAndFlush?

Tags: networking, netty

I recently started using Netty and I downloaded the final release of Netty (3.10) and I am following basic tutorials to get started and write from the client to server, but am having issues.

I am using a channel reference to the server to write using this:

```
channel.write(obj);
```

Where channel is of the type *Channel* but it is never getting received in my handler on the other side (yes my handler is working correctly and receiving connection and disconnections).

I did some research and saw to use channel.writeAndFlush(obj) but this isnt an actual method. I looked at previous beta and alpha releases and the method is there but there are also a number of other changes. So does channel.write(obj) not work or am I missing another step after calling write(obj)? I want to be able to write to the channel at anytime so I wont have a ChannelHandlerContext, only when it is passed to the handler.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:**

In my pipeline I put in a Delimeter, String encoder, String decoder, and my event handler *ServerListener*:

```
new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(server.getConfig().PACKET_BUFFER_SIZE, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()), new StringEncoder(), new StringDecoder(), new ServerListener()
```

on the client side I have those same handlers in the same order, excluding *ServerListener*.

Yet when sending a string down a channel (yes it does print out *Connected To Server*:

```
@Override
public void channelConnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Connection con, ChannelStateEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Connected To Server");
    Channel c = ctx.getChannel();
    c.write("Test");
}
```

The server side doesn't print anything out even though I inherit the messageReceived method and even though the other methods I inherit *channelConnected*) work fine.

Here is my *messageReceived* method:

```
@Override
public void messageReceived( ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Received");
    super.messageReceived(ctx, e);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Netty 3.10 (any version before 4.0), there is no flush since it is implicit.

So when you do a `ctx.getChannel().write(buf)` or `channel.write(bug)`, it shall directly write to the outband.

If not, it probably means an issue on your handler.

You can look at example in: [Example source](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/3.10/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/example)

Comment: Great that's good to know! And yes I have followed that echo tutorial but still get issues. In the main post I posted more information about my pipeline and handlers.

Comment: I actually just tried the echo server example and it didn't work either. It is not receiving anything at all

Comment: I tried adding a custom decoder and attaching it to the server, but when I debug it and I put a breakpoint in the decoder and send an object from the client to the server, it never calls the breakpoint which means its never being received.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out my problem. I was using StringEncoder/StringDecoder in conjunction with ObjectEncoder/ObjectDecoder and they were messing up the bytes of eachother. For some reason this didn't happen earlier but now it does so for those of you who may be getting this same problem, make sure they both arent set as handlers.

Comment: Great you find your root cause for your issue! ;-)